# Iterate over json keys with only EJS

Tags: json, node.js, ejs, key-value

Using only EJS (in EJS templates in .ejs files for NodeJS), how would I iterate over keys of a JSON object (that's not an array)?

I'm looking for something like this:

The JSON object like so:

```
the_object = {
    1: "belongs to id 1",
    3: "belongs to id 3",
    12: "belongs to id 12"
}
```

Some EJS templating like so:

```
<% for (key, value: the_object) { %>
    <li>the key is: <%= key %></li>
<% } %>
```

To produce something like:

the key is: 1

the key is: 3

the key is: 12

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   <%  Object.keys(the_object).forEach(function (key) { %>
    <li>the key is: <%= key %></li>
   <% }) %>
```